# Filter on google sheets minimum across columns

Tags: filter, google-sheets, formula, min

Hi I am trying to do get some data displayed using FILTER function in google sheets.

What i want is the minimum value across 3 columns on 1 row.

Is this possible?

For example:

```
A   1   6   10
B   3   5   9
C   4   4   8
D   5   3   7
A   2   1   6
```

Filter on A should give:

```
A 1
A 1
```

Filter on B should give:

```
B 3
```

I would really like to use filter function but `=filter({A:A,min(B:D)},A:A="A")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if your three (labelled) columns are A, B and C:

```
=filter(A2:C2,A2:C2=min(A2:C2))
```

but in that case filter would be overkill.

Comment: they are being pulled in from another sheet with 1000s of rows once it finds a match i want it to get me the minimum of three columns to be displayed here.

Comment: @ pnuts Let me try to clarify a bit. Assume there is a filter function that returns the match. Now i know that i can get any value in any column associated to that particular row match.

What i want to do is for that particular row, I want to display the **value** which is the minimum out of 3 columns:

`=filter({A:A,min(B:B,C:C,D:D),F:F,min(G:G,H:H,I:I)},A:A=A2)`

This would give me the result: A, B(min value between BCD), F, G(min value between GHI)

Another example:
A, D(min value between BCD), F, H(min value between GHI)

Dont necessarily want the col but the value